# What is the best way to prevent out of memory (OOM) freezes on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

Is there a way to make the OOM killer work and prevent Linux from freezing? I've been running Java and C# applications, where any memory allocated is usually used, and (if I'm understanding them right) overcommits are causing the machine to freeze. Right now, as a temporary solution, I added,

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 10
```

to /etc/sysctl.conf.

Kudos to anyone who can explain why the existing OOM killer can't function correctly in a guaranteed manner,  killing processes whenever the kernel runs out of "real" memory.

**EDIT** -- many responses are along the lines of Michael's "if you are experiencing OOM killer related problems, then you probably need to fix whatever is causing you to run out of memory". I don't think this is the correct solution. There will always be apps with bugs, and I'd like to adjust the kernel so my entire system doesn't freeze. Given my current technical understandings, this doesn't seem like it should be impossible.

Comment: To limit memory, why wouldn't you limit the overcommit to parity?

Comment: The OOM killer on my linux systems seems to work as designed. How sure are you that you are experiencing a OOM killer failure? Why do you think that is the cause? Have you considered the possibility of garbage collector trouble as well?

Comment: @dmckee -- all other applications freeze. @wallyk -- what's "limiting the overcommit to parity"?

Comment: The problem with the OOM killer (and the reason many have said 'just fix the memory problem' is that you can't predict what the OOM killer is going to kill - you can poke it a little bit, but there's no way to be sure it isn't going to kill something pretty vital along the way. Therefore, even if it works, there's no guarantee that the system will actually be usable afterwards.

Comment: The problem is that the OOM killer does not activate soon enough. First the kernel drops all caches and that makes your system freeze. This as a kernel design mistake and/or a distro configuration mistake that should be fixed by the kernel developers. Unfortunately the problem has been there for many years already and it is not getting fixed because people insist on non-solutions such as "buy more RAM" which obviously don't fix the underlying problem. You can recover faster by manually running the OOM killer (SysRq+F) when it freezes but this is a workaround at best.

Comment: The best way would be for Linux to fix this bug - perhaps the most annoying Linux issue ever. It was filed back in 2007 - [System freeze on high memory usage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/159356). Even Windows prevents this by displaying a dialog warning the user about the low memory.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a really basic perl script I wrote. With a bit of tweaking it could be useful. You just need to change the paths I have to the paths of any processes that use Java or C#. You could change the kill commands I've used to restart commands also.
Of course to avoid typing in perl memusage.pl manually, you could put it into your crontab file to run automatically. You could also use perl memusage.pl > log.txt to save its output to a log file. Sorry if it doesn't really help, but I was bored while drinking a cup of coffee. :-D Cheers

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Checks available memory usage and calculates size in MB
# If free memory is below your minimum level specified, then
# the script will attempt to close the troublesome processes down
# that you specify. If it can't, it will issue a -9 KILL signal.
#
# Uses external commands (cat and pidof)
#
# Cheers, insertable

our $memmin = 50;
our @procs = qw(/usr/bin/firefox /usr/local/sbin/apache2);

sub killProcs
{
    use vars qw(@procs);
    my @pids = ();
    foreach $proc (@procs)
    {
        my $filename=substr($proc, rindex($proc,"/")+1,length($proc)-rindex($proc,"/")-1);
        my $pid = `pidof $filename`;
        chop($pid);
        my @pid = split(/ /,$pid);
        push @pids, $pid[0];
    }
    foreach $pid (@pids)
    {
        #try to kill process normall first
        system("kill -15 " . $pid); 
        print "Killing " . $pid . "\n";
        sleep 1;
        if (-e "/proc/$pid")
        {
            print $pid . " is still alive! Issuing a -9 KILL...\n";
            system("kill -9 " + $pid);
            print "Done.\n";
        } else {
            print "Looks like " . $pid . " is dead\n";
        }
    }
    print "Successfully finished destroying memory-hogging processes!\n";
    exit(0);
}

sub checkMem
{
    use vars qw($memmin);
    my ($free) = $_[0];
    if ($free > $memmin)
    {
        print "Memory usage is OK\n";
        exit(0);
    } else {
        killProcs();
    }
}

sub main
{
    my $meminfo = `cat /proc/meminfo`;
    chop($meminfo);
    my @meminfo = split(/\n/,$meminfo);
    foreach my $line (@meminfo)
    {
        if ($line =~ /^MemFree:\s+(.+)\skB$/)
        {
            my $free = ($1 / 1024);
            &checkMem($free);
        }
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Not bad, but maybe not so reliable. Maybe hard ulimits would work? I can't seem to get them to though...

Comment: Sorry, but what did you want to do with hard ulimits? Keep in mind you can only set hard limits as root. There's extra configuration in /etc/security/limits.conf, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If your processes's oom_adj is set to -17 it won't be considered for killing altough I doubt it's the issue here.

`cat /proc/<pid>/oom_adj`

will tell you the value of your process(es)'s oom_adj.

Comment: if `cat /proc/<pid>/oom_adj` do not work, use `cat /proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj`

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple script that'll set the OOM score on launch.  All sub-processes will inherit this score.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") oom_score_adj command [args]..."
  echo "  oom_score_adj  A score between -1000 and 1000, bigger gets killed first"
  echo "  command        The command to run"
  echo "  [args]         Optional args for the command to run"
  exit 1
fi

set -eux

echo $1 > /proc/self/oom_score_adj
shift
exec $@
```

The script sets the score for the local process to the first arg provided.  This can be anything between -1000 to 1000, where 1000 is the most likely to get killed first.  The rest of the arguments are then executed as a command with args, replacing the current process.

Answer (score -1):

I'd have to say the best way of preventing OOM freezes is to not run out of virtual memory. If you are regularly running out of virtual memory, or getting close, then you have bigger problems.

Most tasks don't handle failed memory allocations very well so tend to crash or lose data. Running out of virtual memory (with or without overcommit) will cause some allocations to fail. This is usually bad.

Moreover, before your OS runs out of virtual memory, it will start doing bad things like discarding pages from commonly used shared libraries, which is likely to make performance suck as they have to be pulled back in often, which is very bad for throughput.

My suggestions:

- Get more ram
- Run fewer processes
- Make the processes you do run use less memory (This may include fixing memory leaks in them)

And possibly also

- Set up more swap space

If that is helpful in your use-case.

Most multi-process servers run a configurable (maximum) number of processes, so you can typically tune it downwards. Multithreaded servers typically allow you to configure how much memory to use for their buffers etc internally.

Comment: I made a mistake: I tried to view a 55 GByte XML file.  After a few tens of seconds, the machine froze.  I suspect that part of the problem is that my swap file isn't 55 GBytes in size.
However, it's bad design to let a user space application cripple an entire system.  IMHO, if a single process is using too much virtual RAM, then the kernel ought to kill **that** process, thus freeing the virtual RAM, and allowing the rest of the system to keep going.
It should not be possible for a user application to cause the system to enter a state where the only recourse is to reboot.

Answer (score -1):

First off, how can you be sure the freezes are OOM killer related? I've got a network of systems in the field and I get not infrequent freezes, which don't seem to be OOM related (our app is pretty stable in memory usage). Could it be something else? Is there any interesting hardware involved? Any unstable drivers? High performance video?

Even if the OOM killer is involved, and worked, you'd still have problems, because stuff you thought was running is now dead, and who knows what sort of mess it's left behind.

Really, if you are experiencing OOM killer related problems, then you probably need to fix whatever is causing you to run out of memory.

Comment: once or twice, I've been able to pull up the system monitor before everything freezes.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that fixing stability issues mostly relies on accurately identifying the root cause.  Unfortunately, this requires being able to see what's happening when the issue happens, which is a really bad time to be trying to start various monitoring programs.

One thing I sometimes found helpful was to start a little monitoring script at boot time which would log various interesting numbers and snapshot the running processes.  Then, in the event of a crash, I could look at the situation just before the crash.  I sometimes found that intuition was quite wrong about the root cause.  Unfortunately, that script is long out-of-date, or I'd give a link.