# importing Large JSON file to mongodb returning "killed"

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo, mongoimport

I have a large json file (420mb) and I am trying to import it to mongodb. I have tried by the `mongoimport` method using:

```
mongoimport --db rap --collection colec --file /vagrant/data/data.json --jsonArray
```

It looks like is importing, the output keeps printing that the import process got to 100% but then returns `Killed`.

I tried using pymongo, however, I am not even able to import the json file to python as well. It, also, returns `Killed` when I try:

```
with open('/vagrant/data/data.json') as f:
         file_data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: `killed` is the only thing that returns...

Comment: Sounds like an OOMkiller. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125812/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-out-of-memory-oom-freezes-on-linux helps

Comment: Yes, it is related to your primary memory