# Does Ubuntu or any Linux OS reserve some RAM only for system tasks such as showing desktop home screen and moving mouse pointer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If it does reserve some memory only for system tasks, why does it freeze when the machine runs out of memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to prevent out of memory (OOM) freezes on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125812/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-out-of-memory-oom-freezes-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It sort of does but now I have another question :p. How does one fix the device freezing issue? The same question in the post you shared but also it is not answered I believe.

Comment: Take a look at earlyoom daemon. Seems it helps to prevent freezing for Jupyter Lab users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58518965/72178.